# (Excel VBA) How can I get a button on Excel to display another random cell's data from a list?

Tags: vba, excel, random

I have no prior experience with VBA/Visual Basic/Macros and all that - but I need to create a button that cause a cell to display another random cell's data.

I have a word list of several hundred cells and need a button that will choose one of them to be displayed in a cell at the top of my worksheet. The button needs to be able to be pressed multiple times and still bring up a random word. It doesn't need to have a fail-safe that prevents the same cell being displayed twice in a row.

I don't care how it is accomplished - it just needs to be explained a bit more as I have no idea how VBA works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This site is dedicated to helping users FIX issues with EXISTING CODE.  There are many tutorials on the web for getting started with VBA.  I would suggest breaking your method up into steps and then searching for each part.  You will probably find the code you need here or on another site.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you a starter to assist your learning - (it is Christmas!) and you have the job of researching how to modify it and apply it.  To get you going put this code in a standard code module, adjust the various variables to suit your display/data requirements, add a shape to the spreadsheet and assign this macro to that shape.  My word list is on worksheet "Sheet1"

```
Sub showRandomWord()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim stRow As Long, endRow As Long, dataCol As Long
Dim dispRow As Long, dispCol As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
stRow = 2
dataCol = 3
dispRow = 2
dispCol = 4

    With ws
        endRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, dataCol).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(dispRow, dispCol).Value = _
          .Cells(Application.RandBetween(stRow, endRow), dataCol).Value
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact needs you might not even need VBA,

say you assign the name "data" to the range with the list

in the cell where you want to show the random value put the formula

```
=INDEX(data,INT(RAND()*COUNTA(data))+1)
```

Then a new random value will be shown each time the sheet is recalculated, you can do this manualy by pressing F9 key

If an actual button is required then use VBA , in the buttons event :

```
dim l as long
l=Sheet1.Range("data").count
Sheet1.Range("result")= Sheet1.Range("data").cells(fix((rnd*l)+1),1)
```

here i assume the list is in a range named "data", and the cell where you want the result is named "result"